# Default text format for QTextEdit

Tags: qt, qtextedit, qtextdocument

I don't understand. I setup char format, block format,  root frame format, and page size for all of the text in **QTextEdit** control. And then if I manually delete all the text, and start to type new one, or if I select all text and paste new one from buffer, then voilà! - all the formatting loses.

Is it possible to set some default format for **QTextEdit** (char's, block's, page, etc.)?

Comment: I think the formatting depends on the cursor position. When you change it, the current format may also be changed. I might handle the `currentCharFormatChanged` signal to see what's going on in your text edit and when.

Comment: I handled this signal, and tried to update formatting , and it workes partly. Thanks, you directed me to the right way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved it the next way.

Handled *QTextEdit::currentCharFormatChanged* signal(as vahancho promted), and call *QTextEdit::setTextCursor* with needed formatting cursor. It solves the problem with char and block format.

For the pageSize and rootFrame's format, I've handled *QTextEdit::document::documentLayout*'s *update* signal and if rootFrame format or pageSize of the document was changed, then resetup the needed sizes again.